# c# Entity Framework "Cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I created a sample project using entity framework 4. It was fairly simple, I created a new data model by choosing EF Designer from database. Created the data connection and selected all tables from my database. It seems fine - I am able to see the tables in the designer.

The problem is that then I can't add or delete objects. My db class looks like that:

```
namespace DBAccess
{
    public class DatabaseAccess : IDisposable
    {
        private MyDBModel dbModel;

        public DatabaseAccess ()
        {
            dbModel= new MyDBModel();
        }

        public Accounts AddAccount()
        {
            var A = new Accounts();
            dbModel.Accounts.AddObject(a); // here's the "Cannot resolve symbol 'AddObject'" error
        }

        public void DeleteAccount(Accounts a)
        {
            dbModel.DeleteObject(a); // here's the "Cannot resolve symbol 'DeleteObject'" error
        }
    }
}
```

Why can't I use these methods? I've used them before in other projects..

This is the connection string in the `App.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyDBModel" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDBModel.csdl|res://*/MyDBModel.ssdl|res://*/MyDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyServer;initial catalog=MyDB;persist security info=True;user id=MyUser;password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: dbModel.SaveChanges() ?
using(var dbModel = new MyDBModel){
dbModel.Accounts.Add(new Account{Prop1=...});
dbModel.Savechanges();
}

Comment: Right click on the model and select "Update from database"

Comment: @gillesemmanuel, i have other functions as well, one of them is `Save()` and it saves the changes, but the problem is that when I use `AddObject` it is underlined with an error.

Comment: @Donal, "Update from database" works fine but still it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Show us the code for `MyModel` class.  Looks like you are getting a compilation error telling you that you are calling none existent methods 'AddObject' and 'DeleteObject'

Comment: i find it strange that the EntitySet has the same name as your Entity.
you should have 
var account = new Account();
then
Db.Accounts.AddObject(account);
Maybe i'm wrong. Just trying to figure out what can be the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution, although I'm not sure if it's the right one..

I found this article on Microsoft's website
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556581.aspx

The settings on my data model were different. In `Code Generation Strategy` I have `T4` and `Legacy ObjectContext`. It was set to `T4` and I changed it to `Legacy ObjectContext`. Then under the `.edmx` file I delete the two files with `.tt` extensions. 
In my case they were `MyDBModel.Context.tt` and `MyDBModel.tt`.

Rebuilt the whole solution and it works now.

I hope it will help to someone.